# Magnetic field of permanent magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics

Hi I am looking for some code to (computationally) calculate the magnetic field of a rectangular permanent magnet in 3D space. Preferably I could edit it to add in my own dimensions. Does anyone know of anything?

Comment: Hi Josh - this is a recommendation request, which isn't appropriate for this site, and besides, a lot of computational questions are off topic here. You could ask in [chat] (also try the [chat room for Computational Science](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1878/computational-science))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this guy does it awesomely: http://www.bugman123.com/Physics/index.html
See the links within, which contains scripts.